# I can't write Georgian shrift, when I generate pdf , using django . My code writes black squares besides Georgian letters

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I generate pdf files about each models object, but in pdf, I can't write with Georgian letters, it returns black squares.

Here is some code, I am using `from xhtml2pdf import pisa`
in my urls.py :path('pdf/', views.customer_render_pdf_view, name='customer-pdf-view')

```
def customer_render_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
     pk = kwargs.get('pk')
     customer = get_object_or_404(id, pk=pk)  

     template_path = 'test.html'
     context = {'customer': customer}
     response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
     response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename= "report.pdf"'
     template = get_template(template_path)
     html = template.render(context)
     pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF( 
                 html, 
                 dest=response,
                 encoding='utf-8'
               )   
# if error then show some funny view
    if pisa_status.err:
         return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using a font that doesn't contain your letters. You need to use a font that does have them.

https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=Font#using-custom-fonts